# Make div partial coloured

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this question is asked before and also with good answers, however I still can't get this to work.

What I try to do is make a div partial coloured. The problem I'm facing is that the coloured div needs to overflow a container div.

I'm talking about the blue part. The yellow lines indicate the container div. The blue div on the right actually is as long as on the left, so it spans the width of the page. So left need to be white and right need to be blue.

I tried several things like making the div fixed. That works but that makes the obviously fixed :)

Is there some easy way of accomplishing this? I prefer to do it with CSS instead of static image.

[image]

Comment: Please provide code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: create another child element with white bgcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  /* for reference */
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  /* for reference */
}
.mybar {
  height: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}
.mybar::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mybar"></div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxgamo9w/3/)

Comment: This causes my div to be wider then my screen size. Setting my body to overflow-x:hidden solves the problem. Is that even a good way or I'm I still doing something wrong??

Comment: That would solve it but without seeing the live page I can't tell if it's this causing it or something else. As you can see in the fiddle it's not an issue there.